# Find XPath for like button on youtube comment with CasperJS

Tags: xpath, youtube, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I am beginner programmer with CasperJS and I love to try new things with scraping. My problem:

I am able to login to youtube and like a video, but I cannot find correct XPath for youtube comment like button.

http://tinypic.com/r/2vayr83/8

Here is the part I am stuck on, I always get error:

```
wait timeout of 5000ms expired exiting-
```

so I guess that's because of the incorrect XPath and I want to do that on a specific comment. How could I do that?

```js
casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="update-z132gvlzosmchn30f225wng5gluzgbs5o04"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/img'), function() {
  this.click('//*[@id="update-z132gvlzosmchn30f225wng5gluzgbs5o04"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/img');

  this.capture('like.png')
  this.echo("liked");
});
```

Comment: There is no ID with the value `update-z132gvlzosmchn30f225wng5gluzgbs5o04` in the source of this page.

Comment: Hi,I am new to xpath,this is what i get when I copy xpath from chrome...

Comment: the link to the image is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The Youtube comment thread is loaded in an iframe, so you need to change into the iframe first, before doing something in it. You can use [`casper.withFrame()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#withframe) step function to do this. Keep in mind to select the correct iframe, because there are multiple iframes.

The other thing is that nearly all CasperJS functions only accept CSS selectors by default, but you use an XPath expression for the `click`. You have to use the XPath utility that CasperJS provides to tell CasperJS that the passed string contains an XPath expression and not a CSS selector.

Another problem might be that the iframe is only loaded once it is scrolled into view. You might need to scroll to the bottom. CasperJS provides the `scrollToBottom()` function to do this. You will also need to wait until the iframe is put into the page after you scroll down.

Complete (untested) script:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start(url, function(){
    this.scrollToBottom();
    this.scrollToBottom();
});
casper.waitForSelector('.comments-iframe-container iframe', function(){});
casper.withFrame(1, function(){
  var link = '//*[@id="update-z132gvlzosmchn30f225wng5gluzgbs5o04"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/img';
  this.waitForSelector(x(link), function() {
    this.click(x(link));
    this.wait(1000, function(){
      this.capture('like.png')
      this.echo("liked");
    });
  });
}).run();
```

Comment: Thanks for making this example,but i tried it ,and nothing happens,I got no error... and casperjs got stuck on that step...Maybe this is impossible to do?

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: You probably need to wait for the iframe to be put into the page.

Comment: i have added  this.scrollToBottom(); to make page load comments..and it loads comments....but still it doesen't work...